# Can't run java 8u71 on Iceweasel

Tags: java, debian, iceweasel

What happened to “WebUpd8” team? Banks homepage asking me for java update but couldn't install update via aptitude.

On jessie machine already managed to install and run it via java-package interface, in Iceweasel too.

"We are unable to verify if Java is currently installed and enabled in your browser."

But still having problem with it on Wheezy: could install java but Iceweasel can't find it.

Already tried to manually set the symbolic link in /etc/alternative/

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe worth posting on `askubuntu.com` too.

Comment: maybe worth posting on http://askubuntu.com _only_.

Comment: Should i ask there a wheezy question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of WebUpd8 do not provide Java updates, man could download the linux source from Java website `xxxx.gz`, install `java-package` via `apt-get install java-package` and then run the following:

`$ make-jpkg javaxxx.gz`

Confirm the queries, then it should generate a .deb installable package.

Answer (score 1):

WebUpd8 doesn't seems to work anymore, you can instead `$ sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre` and `$ sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre`, which are the current versions.

Remembering that Firefox doesn't works with it anymore, since version 52.